# managing postgresql database table using the pgadminIII sql tool

Tags: postgresql, sql, spatial-database, pgadmin-3, remote-hosting

i have created a database using postgresql 9.1 and a table containing parcel information for a town council  database on a windows 7 OS. i created the geometry column using the SELECT AddGeomatryColumn function and left the geometry column empty at first. now i want to insert the coordinates of each parcel using the sql tool from the general plan which is in a hardcopy. which query must i use to insert the coordinates one by one? i think i can insert coordinate for each parcel by specifying the erf number of the parcel.

any help please

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have a paper plan of city and you want to create a table with geometries and ref numbers from readed 'manualy' coordinates from this paper map?

Assuming that:

1. Your table name is parcels
2. It have column ref_number and geom

The query could be:

```
insert into parcels(ref_number,geom) values (1,ST_makepoint(wsp_x, wsp_y))
```

You can also:

1. scan the general plan,
2. georeference it,
3. use as underlayer in QGIS,
4. create with QGIS new table in database,
5. add this table as layer and add new points to it.

but that's another story..